# Java Binary I/O Method Stream

Tags: java, binary, filestream

I'm pretty confused on file streaming. I have an input file stream method that will load the file, I can't figure out how to then use the file in another method. The files has one UTF string and two integers. How can I now use each of these  different int or strings in a main method?

```
public static void  dataStream() throws IOException { 

    try (DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(
            new FileInputStream("input.dat"));
    ) {

        String stringUTF = input.readUTF();
        int firstInt = input.readInt();
        int secondInt = input.readInt();

        //System.out.println("File name: " + fileName);


    }

}
```

Comment: You will need to clarify what you mean by _"How can I now use each of these different int or strings in a main method"_. You have three variables that contain the input data you just read.  Write code to so something with the variables.  What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: I want to print them out in a different method

Answer (score -1):

Make an object which happens to do everything you want!

```
public class MyData {

    private final String data;
    private final int one;
    private final int two;

    public MyData(String data, int one, int two) {
        this.data = data;
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    //etc
}
```

And return that from your method:

```
public static MyData dataStream() throws IOException { 
    try (DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("input.dat"))) {
        String stringUTF = input.readUTF();
        int firstInt = input.readInt();
        int secondInt = input.readInt();
        return new MyData(stringUTF, firstInt, secondInt);
    }
}
```

And you can easily utilize this new object:

```
MyData data = dataStream();
String stringUTF = data.getData(); //tada
```

Using objects to perform desired behaviors or storing data is basic OOP principles you should utilize in all your programming.

Comment: Trying it that way I get an error saying getData() is undefined

Comment: well what did you try / how did you go about implementing your solution?